# c++ object gives me an error: pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

I am trying to create my own String class just for practice but I've encountered a problem.
When I compile the program it produces the following error:

"a.out(3013,0x7fff9a0ee3c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff50312ba0: pointer being freed was not allocated *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug Abort trap: 6".

When I create a new object the constructor calls initialize then it enters the if condition and tries to delete the array pointer, however, charArray is not yet initialized to anything so why this is happening? and how can I solve it?

NOTE: when I try to initialize charArray and len in String.h it gives me the following warning:

warning: in-class initialization of non-static data member is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions] size_t len = 0;

```
                                  //class String.h

#ifndef String_H
#define String_H
#define MAX_LEN 60000

class String{

private:

    // Variables and array container
    size_t len;
    char *charArr;

    // Private functions
    void initialize();
    void copyString(const char *);

public:
    // Constructors and destructor
    String();
    String(const char *);
    String(const String&);
    ~String();


};

#endif

                                  //String.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "String.h"
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

// Constructors
String::String(){

    initialize();
}

String::String(const char *arr){

    copyString(arr);
}

String::String(const String& arr){

    copyString(arr.charArr);
}

String::~String(){

    initialize();
}

// Private functions
void String::initialize(){

    if(charArr != 0){
        delete [] charArr;
    }
    charArr = 0;
    len = 0;
}

void String::copyString(const char *arr){

    if(charArr){
        initialize();
    }
    if(arr){
        size_t tempLen = strnlen(arr, MAX_LEN);
        this->len = (tempLen > MAX_LEN)? MAX_LEN : tempLen;
        this->charArr = new char[len + 1]();
        strncpy((char*)this->charArr, arr, this->len);
    }

}

                                 //Main.cpp
int main(){

    String s1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In all of your constructors you are comparing `charArr` and sometimes `arr` and `len` when they are not yet initialized. `c++` does not initialize these to nullptr or 0 for you.

Comment: Even before that, your default constructor will reference an uninitialized `charArr` value.

Comment: "warning: in-class initialization of non-static data member is a C++11 extension" - so compile your code as C++11 or C++14 already. Don't live in the past; use modern C++.

Answer (score 3):

When `initialize` is called by the constructor, the values of `charArr` and `len` are undefined.   So it may execute an unwanted `delete[]`, that is it is *trying to free an array which was not allocated*. Sounds familiar?

Your constructors should initialize member variables to a safe state.

```
String::String () 
    :   charArr{ nullptr }
    ,   len    { 0       }
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking [undefined behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) by applying operator [delete[]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) on an **uninitialized** pointer `charArr` inside your `void String::initialize()` function which is called from your `String::String()` constructor:

```
delete[] charArr; // undefined behavior because charArr is not initialized
```

Since this pointer was not created via operator [new[]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) nor is it equal to `nullptr` then trying to delete it causes undefined behavior. Initialize your pointers / variables prior to using them:

```
String::String() : len(123), charArr(new char[len+1]) {
    initialize();
}
```

The relevant paragraph in the standard describing the issue is: [[expr.delete]#2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.delete#2).